# How can I most effectively use Emacs as an editor alongside XCode?

Tags: xcode, macos, emacs, ide

There are a few tutorials online ([For example](http://mark.aufflick.com/blog/2004/08/23/sensible-emacs-usage-with-apple-s-xcode)) having to do with configuring emacs to work with XCode, but they all seem to be for old versions, and I haven't found one that ties neatly to XCode 3.x + Emacs 23.1 in a way that I can unpack.

So, I'm running XCode 3.1.2 and the Mac Cocoa application build of Emacs 23.1.  I have a passing familiarity with elisp, so modifying configurations doesn't scare me, particularly.  I'd like to be editing my Objective-C code in Emacs, because the XCode editor is painful once you've used a real text editor (snark, snark).

What should I do to make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Emacs.app you can adopt a [cleaner approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275847/tips-for-transitioning-from-emacs-to-xcode/1279528#1279528), and it doesn't require you to change configurations (unless you don't like `make-frame` to be called when a file is opened from XCode, but it's very easy to change).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the customization should be similar to the documentation you pointed to.  With Emacs 23, the server/client code has changed just a little.  Namely, you can start it with the `[--daemon][1]` option to have Emacs start a server in the background.  Then, have XCode just call Emacs using `[emacsclient][2]`.  There are [options](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html#emacsclient-Options) you can use with `emacsclient` to force a new frame (graphical window): `-c`, and you can even start it off with `-a` to ensure you get an emacs if you forgot to start it with `--daemon`.