# Using Emacs with Xcode 4?

Tags: emacs, xcode4

I want to get rid of the slow code editor of Xcode 4 and use Emacs instead. In Xcode 3 I can do this from the [file types preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275847/tips-for-transitioning-from-emacs-to-xcode), but I can't find that in Xcode 4.

How can I change the editor in Xcode 4?

---

If for some reason Apple went crazy and removed this feature from Xcode, is there a way to edit the xcodeproj from within Emacs (add/remove files), as well as build and use the iPhone Simulator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In answer to your questions:

1. Yes, Apple went crazy and removed the ability to associate an alternative editor so you won't be able to automatically use Emacs as an editor within Xcode4 as you did under Xcode3. You will have to setup your project in Xcode4 and (separately) use Emacs to edit source files in the project.
2. You can use the "xcodebuild" command line tool to build your Xcode4 project from within Emacs. Just [Google](http://www.google.ca/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=xcodebuild&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=mzxNTqOTKq7SiALGss2YAQ) or search through [SO earlier messages](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxcode%5D+xcodebuild) for some tips on how people do this.
3. To install your app on the simulator and run it from the command line, read the replies to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187611/how-to-install-iphone-application-in-iphone-simulator).